# How does the pot split in Texas Hold 'Em?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Playing poker with some friends and the software made a decision we don't understand. We need some help understanding a potential three way split in Texas Hold 'Em. Final cards were as follows:

Table: Q♣3♣A♣3♥T⋄

Player 1: A♠T♠

Player 2: Q♥K♥

Player 3: Q♠8♠

Ending up with all three players having Two Pair. Player one with Aces and Tens, players two and three with Queens and Threes. We thought it would be a three way split, but the game say only players one and two would split the pot.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Player one's best five-card hand is A-A-10-10-Q. That's the best hand here, and wins the pot uncontested. Both players 2 and 3 have Q-Q-3-3-A. They should get nothing, unless maybe player 1 was all in and there was further betting? In that case, they might split a side pot, having equal hands.